# A better input method for Chinese in Emacs?

Tags: language-support, emacs, input-language, chinese

I would like to type Chinese in `Emacs`. I followed this [link](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Input-Methods.html), and tried several input methods including `chinese-py`. It seems that, unlike normal IME of an operation system, it is not possible to type more than 1 character one time. We have to type character 1 by 1, this is not convenient at all.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Is Xemacs an option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ibus` with `emacs` (22 or higher) by installing `ibus-el`.

[ibus-el](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ibus-el) [image: Install ibus-el] or `sudo apt-get install ibus-el`

There are instructions for setting it up at [Ibus Mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IBusMode). The instructions were written when `ibus-el` was still a PPA, but the rest of it holds. Slightly updated instructions are also installed to `/usr/share/doc/ibus-el`

If you have installed `ibus-el`, you can ignore most of the instructions. All you need to do is add the following lines to your `~/.emacs` file:

```
    (require 'ibus)
    (add-hook 'after-init-hook 'ibus-mode-on)
```

Something not mentioned in the manual is that Ibus is not listed as in input method in Emacs even after installing `ibus-el`. So there's no need to bother with `C-\`. Just use the Ibus indicator on the menubar to switch input methods like you would with any other application.

Also, Ibus won't see an available input window immediately after Emacs has started. If you try to switch to a Chinese input method at that point using the Ibus indicator on the menu bar, nothing will happen and you might think it's not working. But just click in your file *before* trying to switch the input method (letting Ibus see the available edit window) and then menu bar indicator and Ibus work as normal.

Comment: That's interesting... I have followed your text and managed to switch to `Chinese-SunPinyin` within Emacs and write Chinese. There are 2 problems in Emacs: 1) the `Space` key doesn't work in Chinese mode 2) the shortcuts to switch among input methods (`Alt+Shift_L` or `Ctrl+Space`) don't work anymore. Whereas, they are not problems within other edit windows (e.g. a navigator). Do you have any idea?

Comment: `Space` works fine for me, and so does `Ctrl+Space`. `Alt+Shift_L` is not working for me. To be clear, `Ctrl+Space` enables/disables Ibus while `Alt+Shift_L` switches to the next input method in your list. If you are only using English and a single additional input method, you don't need `Alt+Shift_L`. Emacs seems to be intercepting the `Alt`. You might try using Ibus preferences to bind a different key combo for switching between input methods if you need it and see if that takes care of it.

Answer (score 3):

I use fcitx. It works very well in emacs. But to make the shortcut `Ctrl+Space` work, you have to use the command `env LC_CTYPE=zh_CN.UTF-8 emacs` to start emacs.